# Does Folder wise mail fetching possible into zimbra (postfix) from old server

Tags: postfix, zimbra, email

I had succefully fetch all my old mail server mail in to new zimbra mail server (postfix) using fetchmail...but all mails goes into inbox insted of specific folder....
So does folder wise mail fetching is possible???

thanking you,
sadiq.

Answer (score -1):

If your old server has IMAP support (most do, just not turned on by default) I highly recommend imapsync tool.  That I what I usually use for migrations.

-Cheers, Peter.